# How to force a user program to block 16GB of physical RAM?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operating-system, buffer

I have a 32GB memory machine and I want to simulate trying out one user process to run inside a 16GB machine. One way is to have a tiny user process run and block 16GB physical memory and then go to sleep and then have this former user process to run in the available system.

The problem is that when I write a program to malloc 16GB memory, most of the memory gets blocked from virtual memory and only around 64MB of physical RAM gets blocked. Is there a way to force block physical RAM?

Comment: What do you need that for? You can always run a VM with 16GB RAM, or just pull 16GB out of the PC. What you're doing seems extremely silly.

Comment: [mlock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) or [VirtualLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Linux. I don't have access to temper with the hardware. It's an office server machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux has a kernel parameter to ignore memory beyond a certain size:

```
    max_addr=[KMG]  [KNL,BOOT,ia64] All physical memory greater than or
                    equal to this physical address is ignored.
```

So you could use that. Or look at [`mlock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mmap` using `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `MAP_LOCKED` (the first flag is just to avoid needing a file to create the `mmap`, the `fd` and `offset` parameters are ignored). If `size_t` is not 64 bit, you will need to do multiple `mmap` calls to reach 16 GB.